# When printing emails in Outlook 2003, how to omit headers?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, printing, microsoft-outlook-2003

Whenever I print an email in Outlook 2003, it prints at the top:

> My Name
>
> From
>
> Sent
>
> To
>
> Cc
>
> Subject
>
> etc.

How do omit all that junk and just output the body of the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [print styles](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/CH063564591033.aspx) can be used to change how your emails are printed

**Edit**

If that doesn't work for you, follow the instructions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/outlook/HA010872971033.aspx). It gives you a few methods for doing so. The "Remove headers from the message form" is probably the most integrated method, but will change how you see emails when you jsut view them.

Comment: I've tried this - there is no option to remove the email headers. In the "Format" tab, there Options pane is blank. The only thing I can edit are fonts, paper margins, and page headers (as opposed to email headers).

Comment: The instructions from your second link were helpful.
Seems like my best option is to save as RTF and then print from Word.

Comment: Glad it helped you. It would better if outlook had better printing options...

Answer (score 0):

Dan McG is right.

In Outlook 2003, select File > Page Setup > Define Print Styles. You can make a copy of the default "Memo Style" there (which is the default style used for emails) and edit your copy to remove whichever headers and footers you don't want to see.

Comment: See comment above - this doesn't permit me to remove the message headers.